# Clojure: find repetition

Tags: clojure

Let's say we have a list of integers: `1, 2, 5, 13, 6, 5, 7` and I want to find the first number that repeats and return a vector of the two indices. In my sample, it's 5 at `[2, 5]`. What I did so far is `loop`, but can I do it more elegant, short way?

```
(defn get-cycle
  [xs]
  (loop [[x & xs_rest] xs, indices {}, i 0]
    (if (nil? x)
      [0 i]  ; Sequence is over before we found a duplicate.
      (if-let [x_index (indices x)]
        [x_index i]
        (recur xs_rest (assoc indices x i) (inc i))))))
```

No need to return number itself, because I can get it by index and, second, it may be not always there.

Comment: I think what you want to return is not the vector of the indices that contain duplicates, but the element that are duplicated, at which indices. Something like: #{5: [2,5]}. It doesn't change anything for your example, but what if the input is: 1,2,2,1,1,2,4,4,2,1,4,5,6,7 for example?

Comment: What do you mean by "first" pair? Which pair is first in [1, 2, 2, 1]?

Comment: @tempestadept 2, 2. We go through the list and when we find a number we've seen we say we found it. I use it when track remainders in my program - after remainder duplicated, I have to stop.

Comment: @S4M the result is #{2: [1,2]}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option using list processing, but not significantly more concise:

```
(defn get-cycle [xs]
  (first (filter #(number? (first %))
    (reductions
      (fn [[m i] x] (if-let [xat (m x)] [xat i] [(assoc m x i) (inc i)]))
      [(hash-map) 0] xs))))
```

Comment: +1 for using reductions, always a treat when i get to use it!

Comment: Thanks for reductions! Never paid attention to it. Although solution is not really shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version using [reduced](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reduced) to stop consuming the sequence when you find the first duplicate:

```
(defn first-duplicate [coll]
  (reduce (fn [acc [idx x]]
            (if-let [v (get acc x)]
              (reduced (conj v idx))
              (assoc acc x [idx])))
          {} (map-indexed #(vector % %2) coll)))
```

Comment: `Clojure 1.5` rocks. ;) I should've switched to it long ago.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you have only asked for the first. Here is a fully lazy implementation with little per-step allocation overhead

```
(defn dups
[coll]
(letfn [(loop-fn [idx [elem & rest] cached]
      (if elem
          (if-let [last-idx (cached elem)]
        (cons [last-idx idx]
              (lazy-seq (loop-fn (inc idx) rest (dissoc cached elem))))
        (lazy-seq (loop-fn (inc idx) rest (assoc cached elem idx))))))]
  (loop-fn 0 coll {})))

(first (dups v))
=> [2 5]
```

Edit: Here are some criterium benchmarks:

The answer that got accepted: 7.819269 µs

This answer `(first (dups [12 5 13 6 5 7]))`: 6.176290 µs

Beschastnys: 5.841101 µs

first-duplicate: 5.025445 µs

Answer (score 0):

The intent of your code seems different from your description in the comments so I'm not totally confident I understand. That said, `loop`/`recur` is definitely a valid way to approach the problem.

Here's what I came up with:

```
(defn get-cycle [xs]
  (loop [xs xs index 0]
    (when-let [[x & more] (seq xs)]
      (when-let [[y] (seq more)]
        (if (= x y)
          {x [index (inc index)]}
          (recur more (inc index)))))))
```

This will return a map of the repeated item to a vector of the two indices the item was found at.

```
(get-cycle [1 1 2 1 2 4 2 1 4 5 6 7])
;=> {1 [0 1]}

(get-cycle [1 2 1 2 4 2 1 4 5 6 7 7])
;=> {7 [10 11]}

(get-cycle [1 2 1 2 4 2 1 4 5 6 7 8])
;=> nil
```

Here's an alternative solution using sequence functions. I like this way better but whether it's shorter or more elegant is probably subjective.

```
(defn pairwise [coll]
  (map vector coll (rest coll)))

(defn find-first [pred xs]
  (first (filter pred xs)))

(defn get-cycle [xs]
  (find-first #(apply = (val (first %)))
              (map-indexed hash-map (pairwise xs))))
```

#### Edited based on clarification from @demi

Ah, got it. Is this what you have in mind?

```
(defn get-cycle [xs]
  (loop [xs (map-indexed vector xs)]
    (when-let [[[i n] & more] (seq xs)]
      (if-let [[j _] (find-first #(= n (second %)) more)]
        {n [i j]}
        (recur more)))))
```

I re-used `find-first` from my earlier sequence-based solution.

Comment: OK, when I tell "pair" I mean two numbers in different places.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. These functions are looking for the same number at two different but adjacent indices. Is that not correct?

Comment: It's not correct. I don't want adjacent. I want find a number that has a before it. Say, `1, 2, 5, 10, 13, 5,...` it's `5` and indices are `[2, 5]`.

Comment: I think I get it now. I added a solution at the bottom that doesn't require them to be adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `loop` is a pretty good  choice unless you want to find all duplicates. Things like `reduce` will cause the full scan of an input sequence even when it's not necessary.

Here is my version of `get-cycle`:

```
(defn get-cycle [coll]
  (loop [i 0 seen {} coll coll]
    (when-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]
      (if-let [j (seen x)]
        [j i]
        (recur (inc i) (assoc seen x i) xs)))))
```

The only difference from your `get-cycle` is that my version returns `nil` when there is no duplicates.

Comment: the `reductions` function actually gets around this by providing a lazy sequence of the steps of the reductions, so you can apply a first . filter to it to get the one you want and it won't slurp up the whole original sequence unless there are no matches.